# c++ too few parameters in my overloaded operator ==

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, relational-operators

I am trying to compare two arrays by making an overloaded operator `==`.
My code looks something like this:

```
//myArray.h
class myArray {
    int size, start, end;
    int *data;

public:
    myArray(int sz);
    myArray(int lower, int upper);
    int &operator [](const int index);
    bool operator == (const myArray& index);
};

//myArray.cpp
bool operator == (const myArray& index);
{

}
```

but there is an error in my cpp file where it says:

> too few parameters for this operator function, Function definition for 'operator==' not found.

Any advice/solutions to this error would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your implementation of `operator==` is a free function, not the one your class declared.

Comment: Another recommendation: use `std::size_t` for indices and sizes instead of `int`, as it will always be large enough to represent the maximum number of elements possible on the given platform. E.g. on AMD64, `int` is typically 32bit, but arrays can be larger than 2^32 elements.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 problems with this line right here:

```
//myArray.cpp
bool operator == (const myArray& index);
```

The first problem is trivial. There is no need for the `;` in this context. In fact, putting one there could cause an error.

The second, somewhat more serious one is the fact that `operator==()` is a member function of `myArray`. Thus, you need to preface the definition with the class name just like any other member function:

```
//myArray.cpp
bool myArray::operator == (const myArray& index)
```

Should work fine.

---

Also worth noting is that if you didn't want it to be a member function (which you seem to want, but just in case), you could do this instead:

```
//myArray.cpp
bool operator == (const myArray& lhs, const myArray& rhs)
{

}
```

Then change your declaration to this instead:

```
friend bool operator == (const myArray& lhs, const myArray& rhs);
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator==` in `myArray.cpp` is distinct from `operator==` in `myArray.h`. The latter is a member function of class `myArray`, the former is a standalone non-member function.

The member function form of `operator==` takes one parameter (which is compared to `*this`). The non-member form takes two parameters (which are compared one to the other). Figure out which one you want, and stick to it.